# Wireless does not work on Ubuntu 10.04 but does work on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: intel-wireless, aspire-one

I have Acer Aspire One D257. The wireless does not work at all when using Ubuntu 10.04 . But it works properly when using Ubuntu 11.10 !

So how can I make it work with Ubuntu 10.04 ?

**edit**: I have upgraded the kernel to version 3.2.0 and still no wireless!

Comment: we need more information of your device. What's about 'lspci' 'lsusb' and 'lsmod', we need to know what kind of wireless card is used and which modules are loaded when it's working.

Comment: Seems this notebook use a intel wifi card. Have you install the `linux-firmware` package?

Comment: @peppe84: Thank you so much. `linux-firmware` was installed already. But I did install this version [oneiric linux-firmware](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/linux-firmware) and now wireless works!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved now. The issue is with intel wireless on ubuntu 10.04. So I get the `linux-firmware` from [Oneiric 11.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/all/linux-firmware/download) and it works!

Maybe you will have to upgrade to the latest kernel. you can find all versions here [Kernel.Ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

Thanks to [peppe84](https://askubuntu.com/users/13038/peppe84) :)